# How can I make two or more panels in Java Swing/GUI visible at once without having to press a button?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

I am designing a game for a project in Java Swing using a JForm. I know that you have to use the code

```
jPanel1.setVisible(true);
```

I used this for *all* panels, even in the `init()` method in the source.

I am using the "Layered Panel" option for every panel I add. I placed the image on the first panel:

[image: Game Background]

There are radio buttons in my second panel. I want the user to click on the option while looking at the picture, kind of like clicking on an icon (radio button) on desktop (background image).

Like this:

[image: Game Background with radio button]

When I try to look at my design preview, it just shows me Panel2 (only radio buttons), not 1.

Is it possible to fix this (make two panels visible at once), or should I just make a button to switch between the panels?

Comment: "I know that you have to use the code-

`jPanel1.setVisible(true);`" -- what? no, you **don't** have to do this.

Comment: Please show your [mcve] code so we can see what you're doing right or wrong. If you're using a JLayeredPane (you state "Layered Panel" not sure what that is), then don'. Instead use one JPanel to draw the background image, give it a decent layout manager, and add other JPanels on top of it if needed, but make sure that they are not opaque so that the image shows through.

Comment: @Hovercraft Full Of Eels Oh, okay. So I tried making the panel opaque and that works. Thank you so much!This really helps : )